# Using different user account to login to SQL Server using Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-authentication

We have an installer to create some SQL objects.

For SQL Server we have Windows Authentication. Now the problem is the currently logged in user performing installation does not have access to SQL Server. So we want to provide credentials of some other user and then make connection to SQL Server using this user (Windows Authenticaiton)

Is this possible to impersonate some other user and then connect using Windows Authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to use `runas` for your installer, or the equivalent within it.

Or prompt for credentials.

Comment: even if i prompt for credentials how will SQL connection be made using Windows Authentication i.e. it will connect as if the provided user is connecting?

Comment: It will connect as the user running the process. You'll have to ensure that you use the credentials provided

Comment: i want to connect with the user user account

Comment: well change permissions then in SQL Server!